# Obtain the authorization code through the cURL's command line

Tags: oauth2-playground

I can't find the way to obtain the authorization code with OAuth 2.0 through the cURL's command line for an application that use Google Calendar's API.
Does anybody know how to do it?
Thanks for all the answer.